# Dictionary for learners of modern Greek?

Tags: resource-request, greek

Is there a **learner's dictionary** for present-day Greek? This would be either of the following:

- A monolingual dictionary in which

  - the definitions are written in a simpler subset of Greek,
  - many entries have examples,
  - the lexicon focuses on words that learners need most.
- A bilingual dictionary in which

  - many entries have examples,
  - the lexicon focuses on words that learners need most.

I have found, the [*Oxford Learner's Pocket Dictionary (English-Greek / Greek-English)*](https://elt.oup.com/catalogue/items/global/dictionaries/9780194312790?cc=gb&selLanguage=en) by D N Stavropoulos, but I'm not sure whether this is for Greek learners of English or English-speaking learners of Greek (or both??).

Answer (score 3):

A very good dictionary is available online: [Dictionary of Standard Modern Greek (Triantafyllides)](http://www.greek-language.gr/greekLang/modern_greek/tools/lexica/triantafyllides/index.html)

I don't know of a dictionary that is targeted specifically to people learning Greek. Perhaps somebody else does. The Oxford dictionary (Stavropoulos) is targeted to Greek speakers who learn English. There are many other dictionaries on the market, both monolingual and bilingual and many have a pocket version or a version for young students. One of them may suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, there seems to be a lot of precious information on this website. You mention the Triantafyllides dictionnary which has its definition in "non-beginner" Greek, but apparently there is also a very complete Greek-English dictionary! See: http://www.greek-language.gr/greekLang/modern_greek/tools/lexica/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a a dictionary I just discovered, it is monolingual and specifically oriented towards people learning Greek as a foreign language as it can be deduced from the title:

> Λεξικό της ελληνικής ως ξένης γλώσσας
>   για μαθητές της δευτεροβάθμιας εκπαίδευσης

It is not for complete beginners, of course. I have looked through a couple definitions and they are pretty good with at least one example for each entry.

It is available freely as a searchable PDF. I haven't found a printed edition.

Download link at the bottom of the page:

- [http://museduc.gr/el/εκπαιδευτικα-υλικα/λεξικα/λεξικό-της-ελληνικής-ως-ξένης-γλώσσας](http://museduc.gr/el/%CE%B5%CE%BA%CF%80%CE%B1%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B5%CF%85%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B1-%CF%85%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B1/%CE%BB%CE%B5%CE%BE%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B1/%CE%BB%CE%B5%CE%BE%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8C-%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%82-%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%B7%CE%BD%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AE%CF%82-%CF%89%CF%82-%CE%BE%CE%AD%CE%BD%CE%B7%CF%82-%CE%B3%CE%BB%CF%8E%CF%83%CF%83%CE%B1%CF%82)
- http://museduc.gr/docs/gymnasio/Dictionary2.pdf